# Asp.net 5 and EF7 existing Azure database scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

I am stumped, I want to take my existing azure database and scaffold it in order to do queries of my tables for my website. Every time I run this dnx command it will fail to login. I have double checked my password and username.. I just want to be able to generate code from my existing database to do queries.

This is the command I use according to the documentation.

> C:\Projects\WebApplication>dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source = tcp:random.database.windows.net,1433; Database = MyDatabase; User ID = Username@random; Password = {my_password}; Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = True;" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer

Error given, I am guessing it has to do with my sql connection string, but I do not know what.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'Username'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqlServerScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GetMetadataModel(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GenerateAsync(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseOperations.ReverseEngineerAsync(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, List`1 schemas, List`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<ReverseEngineerAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.<ExecuteAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId: clientid
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
Login failed for user 'Username'.
```

Comment: Post the relevant error in the question itself, rather than as a picture. The error message and the relevant lines from the stack trace should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that from now on. I figured out my problem. . .I am just an idiot. I left the brackets around myPassword in the connection string. . . Thanks Mason, sounds weird coming from a Mason ;).

Answer (score 1):

Unintentionally forgot to remove the curly brackets {} around password in the SQL connection string.

Wrong

```
C:\Projects\WebApplication>dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source = tcp:random.database.windows.net,1433; Database = MyDatabase; User ID = Username@random; Password = {my_password}; Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = True;" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
```

Right

```
C:\Projects\WebApplication>dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source = tcp:random.database.windows.net,1433; Database = MyDatabase; User ID = Username@random; Password = my_password; Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = True;" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
```